# Debugging a "guess the word" game

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a problem in my code. I tried several times but still can't seem to get it right at the bold section. Even though I typed all the letters to become the same, how can I find out the problem?

I am new to coding.

```
import random
import string

def split(word):
    return list(word)

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
list(alphabet)

words = ['hat','pop' ,'cut']

secret_word = random.choice(words)
word_length = print("the length of the word is " + str(len(secret_word)))
correct_letters = split(secret_word)
wrong_letters_storage = []
correct_letters_storage = []

def guessing():

    while True:
        c = 0
        while c <= 3:
            print("")
            print("you have guessed " + str(c) + " times")
            print(correct_letters_storage)
            command = input("guess: ").lower()

            ***if correct_letters_storage == correct_letters:
                print("you win!")
                break***
            elif command == 'quit':
                print("thank you for playing my game")
                break
            else:

                if not command in alphabet :
                   print("pick an alphabet")
                elif command in wrong_letters_storage:
                   print("you have picked this word")
                else :

                    if command in secret_word :
                        print("right")
                        correct_letters_storage.append(command)
                        c += 1
                    elif not command in secret_word :
                        print("wrong")
                        wrong_letters_storage.append(command)
                        c += 1
                    else :
                        print("error")



        return print("you lose")


guessing()
print(correct_letters_storage)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had an very simple error in line 27 and 28. You just simply have a *** in line 27 and 28 you do not need this.
Your wrong lines looked like this:

```
***if correct_letters_storage == correct_letters:
                print("you win!")
                break***
```

Then you have some different errors but they are logical.

First of all in your function split() you could use:

```
word.split('')
```

It would do the same but that is not your main problem.
Then you have a other error. When you try to split your alphabet you don't save it to the variable. The changed line would look like following:

```
alphabet=list(alphabet)
```

Moreover I have changed your checks if you have lost or have won.

```
if correct_letters_storage == correct_letters:
    print("you win!")
    break
elif c>3:
    print('you lose')
    break
```

The fixed lines look like:

```
# importing modules
import random

# the function is splitting a word
def split(word):
    # this works just fine with list(word)
    # but you could also use word.split('')
    return list(word)

#setting the alphabet
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
# here is on error with list(alphabet) you are spliting up the string word but not savng it
# with alphabet = list(alphabet) -> it works
alphabet=list(alphabet)


words = ['hat','pop' ,'cut']

secret_word = random.choice(words)
word_length = print("the length of the word is " + str(len(secret_word)))
correct_letters = split(secret_word)
wrong_letters_storage = []
correct_letters_storage = []

def guessing():
    c = 0
    while c < 3:
        print("")
        print("you have guessed " + str(c) + " times")
        print(correct_letters_storage)
        command = input("guess: ").lower()
        if command == 'quit':
            print("thank you for playing my game")
            break
        else:

            if not command in alphabet :
                print("pick an alphabet")
            elif command in wrong_letters_storage:
                print("you have picked this word already")
            else :
                if command in secret_word :
                    print("right")
                    correct_letters_storage.append(command)
                    c += 1
                elif not command in secret_word :
                    print("wrong")
                    wrong_letters_storage.append(command)
                    c += 1
                else :
                    print("error")
        if correct_letters_storage == correct_letters:
            print("you win!")
            break
        elif c>3:
            print('you lose')
            break





guessing()
print(correct_letters_storage)
```

If you maybe wanted to comment it then use #

```
# this is a comment
```

Moreover you do not need to import the sting module. For me it worked without it.

Comment: For future readers, could you clarify (by way of an edit) what the "very simple error" was. It is easier for people to learn from material where an explanation is provided. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I think you have misunderstood the question - the asterisks were an attempt to show where the error is occuring, and are not actually in the code being run.

Comment: I suspect it is best to wait for the OP to clarify what problem they think is happening on those lines; currently the question looks like it is going to be put on hold. Perhaps the nature of the issue will be clearer once the question is edited with more detail.

Comment: Hi ! thank you so much for your advice however i cant seem to get it working , the loop does not break after i get all 3 characters correct ..  May i know what may potentially went wrong?

Comment: Okay yeah I edited my post it is working now. If that solves your question please mark it as solved.